# Changing DIV background image not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a function like so:

```
function div_id( parent , child ) {
    var children = document.getElementById(parent).childNodes;
    for (var i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].id == child ) {
            return children[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and my div is set up like so:

```
<div id="table_seats_box">
    <div id="table_seat_0">
        <div id="table_seat_0_d"></div>
        <div id="table_seat_0_player_name"></div>
        <div id="table_seat_0_portrait">
           <div id="table_seat_0_card_0"><div id="table_seat_0_card_1"></div></div>
           <div id="table_seat_0_chips"></div>
           <div id="table_seat_0_status"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my code is like so:

```
var t_s_p = "table_seat_" + player_table_position;
var t_s_p_p = "table_seat_" + player_table_position + "_portrait";
var children = div_id ( t_s_p , t_s_p_p );
children.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/class/" + image_id + ".png)";
```

But it does not seem to change the background image.  Am I doing something wrong?  The w, h and visibility is all good on the css.  Thanks for the help.

*edit* fixed the ")" but still not working.

FYI: image is is just a number

Comment: use firebug to find the problem

Comment: did you check if the function div_id(parent,child) returns null, for instance, would work? I don't think it would.

Comment: @nandu Yeah, it doesnt return null.  reza - I use Chrome, no errors.  Miszy - image_id is just 0.

Comment: @Ohmages : it may not return null now .. but what if it does :) ..thats the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing the `url(` opening parenthesis, change your `backgroundImage` definition to:

```
children.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/class/" + image_id + ".png)";
```

**Note:** you can optionally simplify your `div_id` function:

```
function div_id(parent, child) {
    return document.getElementById(parent).querySelector("#" + child); /*IE8+, all other modern browsers*/
}
```

Comment: Ah, I did not even see that and ive been trying to figure this out for a while.  However, your function says: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDIVElement> has no method 'getElementById'.  And its still not working.

Comment: If I take table_seat_0_portrait, and just close it (so it doesnt have any divs inside of it.  i.e <div id="table_seat_0_portrait"></div>  it will work.  :/

Comment: @Ohmages Is it possible that the children of `table_seat_0_portrait` have background images that are covering the one for the portrait?

Comment: Yeah they do, that is the problem, I didnt even think about that since I thought, it would just push the divs.

Comment: @Ohmages Glad it's fixed; don't forget to accept this answer if it worked for you!